# Is there a GPU-hashrate database?

Tags: mining, gpu, hashrate

Is there a database that lists GPU models and their approximate mining hashrates?

Answer (score 5):

it does seem the above mentioned lists are no longer available. so try this one, its up to date and recent.
[GPU hash comparisons](https://www.techspot.com/article/1438-ethereum-mining-gpu-benchmark/)

Answer (score 3):

Try this one: 
http://cryptomining-blog.com/category/mining-hardware/

Though it is not perfect, it covers most of the GPUs.

Answer (score 3):

there is a database of GPU different models and their hashpower (with the usage conditions)
check http://www.mininghwcomparison.com/list/index.php

Answer (score 2):

[mininghashrates](http://www.mininghashrates.info) is a database with GPU hashrates that can be filtered and searched.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/ZCash_mining_GPU_Comparison) is a zcash hash rate list, but it is pretty comprehensive. I use mainly to check wattage usage.

Answer (score 0):

[GPU lister](http://www.gpulister.com/) is a search platform for different graphics cards of different credential with their configurations such as **Hashrate, Core clock, Memory Clock, Power consumption for specific algorithm** and many more specifications.

I request all of you to visit the website and submit your best hashrate for others.

Comment: www.gpulister.com/ does not seem to have a DNS record. The site does not exist.

Comment: @ThorkilVærge It does now. Maybe the op was a bit too impatient with the DNS propagation.