# Which graphics card is currently the best for mining?

Tags: mining

Which graphics card is currently the best for mining (mhs-watt-ratio)? 
I'm using the R9 280x which generates about 13 mhs.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: The ones that are sold out :p You can try looking up cards by hashrate https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16747/is-there-a-gpu-hashrate-database and then looking up mining wattages separately. I'd guess it's an RX470/480 or the 1070TIs based on the sold-out status (or the RX570/RX580). I wouldn't put a lot of faith in the wattage numbers people put out, though. Maybe someone here is into mining and has tried a lot of cards, has good measurement methodology, and good notes. Few review sites ever put out any useful (or even meaningful) electricity measurements of anything.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the **GPU AMD RX480 and RX580** are the most popular mining cards due to their low electricity consumption and their medium hashpower. Here is a [benchmark](http://gpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/AMD-RX-580-vs-AMD-RX-480/3923vs3634) between these two. after these cards we have the less popular the Nvidia 1070 with a higher hashrate and power consumpation. The chart below showes you an estimation about the different hashpower.
[image]